# How to verify a Discord account by email or phone for free using Python?

Tags: python, discord, verification

I am creating a Discord token generator but I have to verify an account with a phone number, my question Is there a way to verify a Discord account by email or phone for free using Python? (clearing cookies or set incognito browser mode doesn't work :( )
Note: I use a random email

Answer (score 1):

I wouldn't advise stealing others discord accounts, but heres a few tips, but non development related. Python cannot generate phone number and discord gives you warnings saying that you need to verify if they suspect an alternative account. If you simpy clear your cookies before logging into another account using the token, you won't be prompted at all to verify a phone number

Comment: Clearing cookies is not working :-(

Comment: Try clearing other data, or going into incognito mode

Comment: also if you would really like to automate it, there are a couple exetremely useful sms and email APIs.

When you cleared the cookies, did you still have the discord page open? I think it might log the cookie again if you had it open

Comment: i try to clear cookies and set incognito borwser mode
and doesn't word  ;-(